# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-camera2, illegalargumentexception, receiver

I am developing a flashlight app that switch on/off the system tourch.

I have a crash that shown on Android M (v6.0) on

> Crashlytics

Here is the Issue details and stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$1@49e5f1b
   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:789)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1222)
   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$3.run(CameraManager.java:1266)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I have the following `Manifest` permissions and hardware features:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

****EDIT:****

Here is the code I am using to access the camera:

```
// Here, I am checking if SDK >= M
if (VersionUtils.isMarshmallowOrGreater()) {

        cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        if (cameraManager != null) {

            try {
                cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            } catch (CameraAccessException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

} else {

        if (camera == null || camera.getParameters() == null) {

            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

Here is the code to switch on the flash/tourch:

```
if (VersionUtils.isMarshmallowOrGreater()) {

            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

 } else {

            if (camera == null || params == null || camera.getParameters() == null) {
                getCamera();
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);

            startCameraPreview();

 }
```

Also, here is the code of switching off the camera flash:

```
if (VersionUtils.isMarshmallowOrGreater()) {

            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

 } else {

            if (camera == null || params == null || camera.getParameters() == null) {
                return;
            }

            try {

                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                stopCameraPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 }
```

Code of `startCameraPreview()` method:

```
private void startCameraPreview() {
    try {
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't have any receiver in my app except the widget provider class but I don't have any line of code the do (register/unregister) a receiver!!

I searched and read many links resources regarding this issue but I could not find any clue to exactly know the line which causing it.

Anyone faced this issue, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml file? see my github repo at https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/FlashLightWidget

Comment: @ChiragSavsani, yes, I will update my question with permissions used in the manifest

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259429/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-receiver-not-registered

Comment: @ChiragSavsani, Thanks for sharing the link. I read that question before and did not find a clue to solve my issue :(

Comment: @PerracoLabs, yes I am asking the user either to allow or deny the Camera permission

Comment: @PerracoLabs, I don't have any receiver to register in my app. If I have then I can easily handle it but the weird thing is that I can't reproduce the issue and In which line the crash hides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue (or similar). My stacktrace was exactly as yours. I've solved my problem by ensuring (in the code of my application) that I don't try to switch torch Off if the torch was not turned ON by my application previously.

Crash occurred when I was calling `cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)` two times sequentially.

So I just maintain boolean flag in my application which shows exact torch state at the moment. Set it to true right after `cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)` call and don't do `cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)` if the flag in not true. Set the flag to false after successful `cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have access to `CameraManager` from both my `Activity` and an `IntentService` class which the second can turn on/off the flash. According to what you said, I need to use this boolean in both activity and intent service ?

Comment: You need one flag which will be visible in both places: Activity and IntentService.

Answer (score 1):

**`Camera.Parameters` is deprecated in API level 21. Use `CameraManager` instead.**

For `setFlashMode (String value)` in `Camera.Parameters`, there is an equivalent method `setTorchMode (String cameraId, boolean enabled)` in `CameraManager`

Comment: If you carefully read the exception, its happening when using the 'CameraManager'. In my code, I'm using the old and the new way to access the camera with permission check. Its really weird exception.

Comment: I edited my question. Note that, I can't figure out where the problem is and in which line as I don't have any receiver in my app to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Hi the log cat you have posted looks like only a small part. Is there anything else?

Comment: Actually this is the only thing I got in the logcat :( . If I have some more, I would be happy to post it out

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Do you get this error every time when you run the code in Marshmallow or is it a rare case? 2) When does this on/of code executes? I mean on what actions?

Comment: Also can you elaborate    "I don't have any receiver in my app except the widget provider class but I don't have any line of code the do (register/unregister) a receiver"   ? What is widget provider class?

Comment: Q1) Its a rare case. Q2) on and off codes are executed when user clicks on the switch on/off button. I am using a boolean to check if flash is on/off to do this logic. As per your next comment, I don't have any `BroadcastReceiver` to call `register/unregister` it in my `Activity`. I only have an `AppWidgetProvider` class that is used to inflate a widget on user's home screen, this class is registered in the `Manifest` file as `<receiver>...</receiver>`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post ([When trying turn off camera led, app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955071/when-trying-turn-off-camera-led-app-crash)) is helpful.

In short,
f you try to disable flashlight again (even if flashlight is already disabled), then app is crashed.

Comment: I already had commented on that post but unfortunately the onwer could not help me as he forgot how the code was

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but I think in new mobiles there are many camera and maybe camera 0 does not have flash but camera 1 have that so I just search I found this solution if someone still have this issue

```
     // Check if the device has a rear-facing camera
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        // Get the list of camera ids
        String[] cameraIds = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
        
        // Check each camera for flash availability
        for (String cameraId : cameraIds) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            
            // Check if the camera has a flash unit
            Boolean hasFlash = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
            
            if (hasFlash != null && hasFlash) {
                // Flash is available for this camera, you can proceed with accessing and controlling it
                // Your code to interact with the flash
                break; // Exit the loop since we found a camera with flash
            }
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    // The device doesn't have a rear-facing camera, handle this situation accordingly
    // For example, disable flash-related features or display a message to the user
}
```